# Python Virtual Environment Operator DAG No Longer Works in Airflow Upgrade

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have the following PythonVirtualEnvOperator DAG that runs without issue in Airflow 2.2. In Airflow 2.7.2 however it returns: `ValueError: The key 'data_interval_end' in args is a part of kwargs and therefore reserved.` I've tried playing around with how `'{{ data_interval_end }}'` is passed in and am unable to figure it out.

I've instead gone ahead and removed the entire `op_args=['{{ data_interval_end }}'],`from the PythonVirtualEnvOperator, and the corresponding `data_interval_end` paramter from `process()`. It now keeps returning:

`file.write_bytes(self.pickling_library.dumps({"args": self.op_args, "kwargs": self.op_kwargs}))`
`TypeError: cannot pickle 'module' object`

But I'm not passing it any `op_args` or `op_kwargs`. Any ideas on how to get this thing to run?

```
def process(data_interval_end, dag_run):
     pass
    
        
    with DAG(
                    dag_id='da_survey_presentation',
                    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
                    schedule_interval='0 8 * * 1',  # run once a week at midnight Pacific every Monday morning
                    max_active_runs=1,
                    catchup=False,
                    concurrency=1,
                    on_failure_callback=partial(on_failure, stage),
                    sla_miss_callback=partial(sla_miss, stage),
                    start_date=datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1),
                    is_paused_upon_creation=(stage != 'prod'),
                    tags=['da']
             ) as dag:
                PythonVirtualenvOperator(
                    task_id="virtualenv_task",
                    python_callable=process,
                    op_args=[
                        '{{ data_interval_end }}'
                    ],
                    provide_context=True,
                    requirements=["google-api-python-client==1.6.7", "df2gspread==1.0.4"],
                    system_site_packages=True,
                    dag=dag
                )
```